# dask future not updating according to progress

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, future, dask

problem...

1. I am submitting function to dask client and recording the futures keys.
2. I am using these key to instantiate the futures in a different fucntion.
3. **These futures are stacked in "pending" mode**

### backbone of the program I am trying:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, Future
client = Client()

def func1(client, data):
    future = client.submit(some_long_function, data)
    key = future.key
    return key

key = func1(client, data)

def func2(key):
    future = Future(key, client)
    print(future)  # !! Always show "pending" even when the process finished !
```

How can I use the "key" of a future to get the status of the run and retrieve the results when done ?

(NOTE: I don't want to use the "Future" object itself, since I would like to send this "key" to a client javascript application)

Answer (score 1):

When the future gets garbage collected in `func1` the client sends a message to the scheduler that it no longer needs the result and so it probably never runs.  You probably want to call `fire_and_forget` on the future to ensure that it runs, even if you don't hold a reference to the future.

See these docs:

- [Futures](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html)
- [`fire_and_forget`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/futures.html#distributed.fire_and_forget)